# Is there a way to automatically save the system state when kernel panic occurs?

Tags: kernel, kernel-panic

Is there a way to `save` the overall state of the system when `kernel panic` occurs?
`Kernel panic` occurs during operation.
However, when `kernel panic` occurs, I can not debug through tty!
If kernel panic happens, I connect the tty debug cable to the board and check it with teraterm.
In this situation, the terminal does not work.
Do you dump system status (dmesg, process status, memory, etc ,,,) to file when `kernel panic` occurs or does this exist?
I would like to debug the situation in which `kernel panic` occurs.

Comment: You get no response after kernel panic because there's nothing running anymore - the kernel has quit. However, most logs should still be in their normal place, and up until the kernel stopping ought to have useful information. If it is a repeating occurrence and the normal logs don't help, try increasing verbosity of related log generators to capture more data.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver Thanks for your advice. Currently there is a kernel panic message in kern.log, so I'm using the contents.